# Laravel, pass variable to view

Tags: php, laravel

I have a doubt. I have been checking laracasts and they show some examples of passing variable(s) from router to a view:

```
Route::get('about', function() {
    $people = ['Eduardo', 'Paola', 'Chancho'];
    return view('about')->with('people', $people);
});

Route::get('about', function() {
    $people = ['Eduardo', 'Paola', 'Carlos'];
    return view('about')->withPeople($people);
});
```

The second example, I am not sure how Laravel handle it. I know it works I have test it, but which pattern they use? why is it possible to handle a dynamic variable.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I guess I miss that part, any specific comment instead of a general link?

Comment: You did not even understand the question. you should receive a penalty for downvoting with no reason and giving pointless answer...

Comment: Guys, please look at the question. It's a very valid question. Don't downvote like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one is handled by Laravel through php's [__call](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) magic method. This method redirects all methods that start with 'with' to the with method through this code in the `Illuminate\View\View` class:

```
public function __call($method, $parameters)
    {
        if (Str::startsWith($method, 'with')) {
            return $this->with(Str::snake(substr($method, 4)), $parameters[0]);
        }
        throw new BadMethodCallException("Method [$method] does not exist on view.");
    }
```

As you can see if the method starts with 'with' `(Str::startsWith($method, 'with')`, Laravel redirects it to the with method `return $this->with` by taking the first param as the string that follows 'with' `Str::snake(substr($method, 4))` and the second param as the first param that was passed `$parameters[0]`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome that was the answer I was looking for. There should be penalty for downvoters with no reason.

Comment: Cheers @Eduardo, they didn't understand the question. I'll upvote you to get the count back to zero

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works.

```
Route::get('about', function() {
    $people = ['Eduardo', 'Paola', 'Chancho'];
    return view('about',compact('people'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to pass data in view

```
Route::get('about', function() {
$data['people'] = ['Eduardo', 'Paola', 'Chancho'];
return view('about')->withdata($data);
});
```